# This code is not creating HMAC signature. I have to create HMAC signature through C#.NET, how can I create?

Tags: c#, hmac, hmacsha1

Here is my code, what format of input string should I use or what actual format is there of input string? What should be the prn number? Or can we assume any 10 digit number as prn to get output?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace HMCApp2
{
    class Sha1HashProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string key = "<my private key>";
          //  string data = "'mrj'.'json'.'539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3'";

            string data = "json539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e31234567890";
            string secret = Sha1HashProgram.ShaHash(data, key);
            Console.WriteLine(secret);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string ShaHash(string value, string key)
        {
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)))
            {
                return ByteToString(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)));
            }
        }

        static string ByteToString(IEnumerable<byte> data)
        {
            return string.Concat(data.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried it in another way but still not working, Here is my another code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string Encode(string input, byte[] key)
        {
            HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            return myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream).Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + String.Format("{0:x2}", e), s => s);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my private key");
            string input = "";
    //        foreach (string s in new string[] { "Marry", " had", " a", " little", " //lamb" })
    //        {
     //           input ="'mrj'.'json'.'539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3'";
                input = "json539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e31234567890";
                System.Console.WriteLine(Encode(input, key));
   //         }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried in that way as told by Martin, now I am getting the HMAC signature but it is not showing me the json when I paste it to URL,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

namespace HMCApp2
{
    class Sha1HashProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string key = "<my private key>";

         //   string data = "json539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e31234567890";
            string data = "539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3";
            string secret = Sha1HashProgram.ShaHash(data, key);
            Console.WriteLine(secret);
 //           Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string ShaHash(string value, string key)
        {
           // using (var hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)))
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA1(StringToBytes(key)))
            {
               // return ByteToString(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)));
                return ByteToString(hmac.ComputeHash(StringToBytes(value)));
            }
        }

        static string ByteToString(IEnumerable<byte> data)
        {
            return string.Concat(data.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        }

        static Byte[] StringToBytes(String hexString)
        {

            return Enumerable.Range(0, hexString.Length / 2).Select(i => (Byte)Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(2 * i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `ASCII.GetBytes` is not the inverse of your `ByteToString`. If your '<my private key>' is in hex and you intend to use it as bytes, you need to use a different conversion method.

Comment: @Anton Tykhyy, okay my private key is in hex then which method should I use? or would you suggest.

Comment: Use `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary`.

Comment: Okay Anton, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out by Anton Tykhyy in the comments the code `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` cannot be used to convert a string of hex digits to bytes. Instead you can use this function (it will throw various exceptions if the input is not a valid hex string):

```
Byte[] StringToBytes(String hexString) {
  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, hexString.Length/2)
    .Select(i => (Byte) Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(2*i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
    .ToArray();
}
```

Calling `StringToBytes("539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e31234567890")` will return an array of bytes: `0x53, 0x9F, 0xF0, ...`.

Comment: Ya it is throwing Exceptions, so what is the correct format I have tried two formats of the input string such as,  input="'mrj'.'json'.'539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3'"; input="json539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e31234567890"; both are not working which one should I use? One is of adding station code format and public api key. And the other is, format+apikey+pnr no.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni: You have to remove the `json` in front. Just supply the hex string.

Comment: Thanks Martin, it happened, it gave me the HMAC signature but when I put that signature in my URL, in the following format,   http://pnrbuddy.com/api/station_by_name/name/delhi/partial/1/format/json/pbapikey/539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3/pbapisign/b7e4ce7192abe2621b5cb3efbab0368d74470c7d  it is again giving the error that {"error":"UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS. HMAC SIGNATURE MISMATCH."}. Is that we have to pass only public api key in hex format or we have to pass it along with the pnr number at the end of it.

Comment: After removing that pnr added at the end and supplying only the hex string yet it is giving the same error, {"error":"UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS. HMAC SIGNATURE MISMATCH."} what would be the reason.